# How to rebuild FreeBSD-native LLVM/Clang on FreeBSD, or how to get the source code?

Tags: build, kernel, clang, llvm, freebsd

When I use the original versions (even 3.4.1) of LLVM/Clang to build FreeBSD kernel, it always has problems.

Since I need to modify something in LLVM source and then build the kernel, where can I get the FreeBSD-friendly Clang/LLVM source code (3.5 is better), or rebuild LLVM/Clang directly on FreeBSD? (it seems /usr/src/contrib/llvm/ has some source code but no Makefile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New versions of Clang and LLVM are in ports/packages (eg. "pkg install clang35").  If you want to easily rebuild it with your changes, do "portsnap fetch update" to update your ports, "cd /usr/ports/lang/clang35", "make configure", then apply your changes to sources in /usr/ports/lang/clang35/work/ directory, and then do "make all install".

To rebuild LLVM version in the FreeBSD source tree, use the Makefiles in /usr/src/usr.bin/clang.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest 3.5 source code via:

```
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/branches/release_35 llvm
cd llvm/tools
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/branches/release_35 clang
```

Then run

```
./configure --enable-optimized --disable-assertions
make
make install
```

in the top dir.